Shared database .MDF for two separate projects "C#,WINFORM"
I created a project to generate the license key for a main project. This project must save the license key in the main project database, in the license table. If I use the same path with DataDirectory for both projects, a second instance of the database will be created and I will not be able to retrieve the license key from the main project because it will be saved in the second instance. and I can't use an absolute path, because I will configure an installer for the projects to deploy them to different clients. Please help me.
C#, Winforms, ADO.NET
Thank you.
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="maDatabase" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database_Inovatio.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>


Well, and what are you expecting us to do? Either you have the same relative path which leads to different absolute paths and therefore to multiple copies of the database on the different clients, or you specify an absolute network path indicating a single location on a common server to share one database.

AttachDbFilename does this, most people don't realize and use it anyway. Don't use it (ever), instead attach your database normally using CREATE DATABASE

Using LocalDB like this in productions is meaningless. LocalDB is a feature of SQL Server Express which means you must install Express to begin with. At this point you can just restore or attach the database and connect to it normally, from as many clients as you want. LocalDB is only meant for development

Agree with P.K.      https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string#sql-server-express-localdb     SQL Server Express is not recommended for use in production web applications. LocalDB in particular should not be used for production with a web application because it is not designed to work with IIS. However, a LocalDB database can be easily migrated to SQL Server or SQL Azure.

It is a desktop application. Actually, I'm a beginner, and I don't understand what the problem is exactly.

How's the user supposed to use your apps? Ideally when you run the license APP, you should somehow point to the Main applicatiion Path, upon which it should be a no-brainer to open the localdb from that Path. I don't see how any of this should be a problem to code
